# Frostwire does not start

Tags: openjdk, installed-programs

I downloaded Frostwire from [this](http://www.frostwire.com/downloads) page. After downloading, it appeared in the Software Center and supposedly installed it. The problem is simple: Frostwire does not open, the icon blinks but nothing happens.

I have read it may be a wrong version of OpenJDK, I have OpenJDK Java 7; but I do not know how to change that.

Comment: You've tagged your question with `software-centre`. However, I'm not able to locate anything called "frostwire" there. [Search "frostwire" op SC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=frostwire&op=). Please clarify by **editing** your question on how you installed it.

Answer (score 0):

it should be able to run using the openjdk 7. Make sure that if you have another java in the system, the default version is Java 7.

In order to help you can you please do this for me:

1. Open a Terminal
2. type "frostwire", press Enter
3. Copy and paste all the output here, so we can see exactly the error.

Make sure you have the latest FrostWire .deb download (5.6.2)